# Determine if Control key was used to generate character in WM_CHAR

Tags: winapi

When receiving character input, is there a way to know whether the character code in `wParam` was generated as a result of the keyboard state we get back from `GetKeyboardState()`?  For example, if you hit `Ctrl+A` then the character 'a' would not be a result of the control key but if you're using a Swedish keyboard and type `Ctrl+Alt+7` the result would be `{`.  In that case, is there any way of knowing that the keyboard state (`Ctrl` and `Alt`) were necessary to generate that character code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To be honest, as an English speaker who has really only ever used a US keyboard layout, I have no definite idea that this will work, but...) I believe that the `VkKeyScan` function (or `VkKeyScanEx`) might do what you want.

As input, it takes a character, not a scan code or a virtual key, so this is the `wParam` value that you get from `WM_CHAR`.

Its return is a value that provides both the virtual-key code (which I guess you can ignore) in the low-byte, and the (mis-named) "shift state" in the high-byte, which is actually a set of flags representing the qualifier keys needed to produce that character.

So if you get a `WM_CHAR` message and wanted to tell if the control key was needed in order to generate it, in theory you could do:

```
case WM_CHAR:
    if (HIBYTE(VkKeyScan((TCHAR)wParam)) & 2) {
        // control pressed!
    }
    break;
```

Comment: woot!  I'm experimenting with this right now and it looks like I can solve my problem with this. Thanks very much Jonathan, I really appreciate it!

Comment: For some reason, the hi byte has the bit flag of `2` for SHIFT as well as for CTRL

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking at the data provided by the `WM_CHAR` message, then no.  You would likely have to look at the `WM_KEY...` messages to keep track of what the surrounding keystrokes where doing at the time, if `Get(Async)KeyboardState()` does not provide what you need.

Comment: I can look in `WM_KEY...` also. Do you have any suggestions about what I should be looking at from there?